# Run a validation script before allowing any commit in a given repo

Tags: bash, git, scripting

I want to run a script locally whenever someone in RepoA, makes a commit on a branch

```
currentBranch=$(git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD)

if [[ $currentBranch = *"my-"* ]]; then
  echo "contains my"
else
  echo "Hold on there! you need to rename your branch before you commit!
  "
fi
```

I have this running so far which works, whenever I run `npm run test:script` it runs > `"test:script": "./branchname.sh"`

however, I have some issues. one how can I run this every time someone commits?

I have tried putting it in my package.json

```
  "pre-commit": [
    "lint",
    "test:script"
  ],
```

but it doesn't run on *every* commit

also, how can I get the commit itself to abort if the script fails, i.e. jump into the else block

Comment: I don't think sticking pre-commit config in the package.json will automatically make it run. Look into the `git-hooks` package.

Answer (score 5):

You can take advantage of git hooks. There is a bunch of files you can find in your `.git/hooks` folder whitin your project folder.

Here the full documentation: https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks

Note that you need to give exec permissions to hook files.

Hooks can be basically bash files, so you can abort the commit exiting with a value != 0.

Here an example: https://github.com/xyzale/my-stuff/blob/master/git/hooks/pre-commit

In order to share the hooks with your collaborators you can add a `hooks/` folder to your repository and either symlinking it to `.git/hooks` or editing the git config about the hooks location through the command

```
git config core.hooksPath hooks
```

Comment: hi, this looks good. one question though. to get it work I had to run `chmod u+x` etc. would I have to get all the people using the repo to run this before the command would run? I would prefer this not to be the case as otherwise people could still commit invalid branch names up

Comment: thanks for the update. it seems a bit pointless adding all this considering each person will have to `chmod` to give permissions, I want something that runs automatically

Comment: When you add files to the repo, git tracks the permissions of files too

Comment: ok so I ran `git commit` and in my hooks folder I have a file called `pre-commit` with the script in...and nothing happened?

Comment: well... this is how it works, I can't troubleshoot for you :) ... it might be something related to your pre-commit file content, i have no clue.

Comment: sorry im getting confused. should the pre-commit file inside .git have anything? if yes, then what is the point of the extra hooks file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171234/discussion-between-xyzale-and-the-walrus).

Comment: @TheWalrus, it's deliberate that everyone has to approve this -- it'd be a major security hole otherwise, if interacting with any git repo you clone from anywhere on the internet could run arbitrary code. (Yes, once you run `make` or similar you're _agreeing_ to run arbitrary code, but it should only happen after the user agrees/approves; `git commit` isn't generally understood to grant that approval).